# InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I'm using SeleniumLibrary for Robot Framework and i do have an issue regarding of Input Text function:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="gngFeeValue" >What is the expected Fee Value?</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input id="gngFeeValue" data-role="numerictextbox"
                                        data-format="###,###,###,###,###,##0"
                                        data-decimals="0"
                                        data-spinners="false"
                                        data-bind="value: gng.feeValue, disabled: isInputDisabled" placeholder="Enter fee value" />
        </div>
</div>
```

TEST.robot:

```
Expected Fee Value - Value

[Arguments]    ${expectedFeeValue}
Input Text   //*[@id="gngFeeValue"]    ${expectedFeeValue}
```

I do get an error:

```
InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
```

Anyone who could help me regarding this? Thanks!

Comment: Is the textbox grey-out or disabled?

Comment: Would you accept an answer in `selenium-python` without any reference to `robotframework`?

Comment: the textbot neither grey-out or disabled. you can input numbers there then it will change base on the format

Comment: In the provided source code there are attributes `.. data-bind="value: gng.feeValue, disabled: isInputDisabled" ` that strongly suggest there is more functionality than meets the eye. Have you tried first clicking on the element before the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webElement your are trying to interact with is either not clickable or it is disabled or may be it is out of browser's viewport. Selenium API is successful only on active interact-able webelements. Use **Javascript**, as a last mile solution.

Comment: With respect to the viewport, your statement is incorrect. Interaction with an element that is loaded on the page, but requires scrolling to come into view are intractable as long as they are part of the DOM. Presently a lot of sites use lazy loading to load the remaining elements into the DOM when scrolling. This is different and should not be mistaken for out-of-viewport.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I couldn't find any elements on a specific form.

I realized that I could use the elements outside the form normally. So I started investigating html and found that it was inside an **iframe**.

To solve this, I only needed the [SeleniumLibrary Select Frame](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Select%20Frame):

```
Select Frame                        xpath=//*[@id="iframe"]
```